# Reverse every other row in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a tensor `input` of undefined shape `H x W`, I would like to reverse every other row.

In numpy, I would simply do

```
input[1::2, :] = input[1::2, ::-1]
```

but this is apparently not possible in TensorFlow.

Note that the input shape is only *partially-known*, i.e., `input.shape == (None, None)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the number of rows known to be even, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: @user1735003 it is arbitrary :) that makes it harder

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using placeholder

```
input = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32)
# define axis to reverse
axis_to_reverse=1
input_reversed = tf.reverse(input, [axis_to_reverse])

sess = tf.Session()
_input_reversed = sess.run(input_reversed, {input: your array})
```